# QComboBox text colour won't change with style sheet

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to style a combobox in QT5. I'm using QT Creator for the layout and loading an app-wide style sheet at start up.

The css I have related to my combobox is as follows:

```
QComboBox
{
    color:white;
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1,y2:1, stop: 1 rgba(228, 41, 81, 100), stop: 0 rgba(234, 107, 101, 100));
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,200);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}

QComboBox QListView
{
    border-style: none;
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1,y2:0, stop: 1 rgba(228, 41, 81, 100), stop: 0 rgba(234, 107, 101, 100));
}

QComboBox::drop-down
{
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px;
    border-color:white;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow
{
    image: url(:/ArrowImages/images/whitearrowdown16.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

But the text colour in the combo box remainds as the default (black) colour. The colour in the drop down is white. The border colour and styling all work correctly. Is the label on the combobox some sort of sub-control I need to style separately? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks.

Edit:

Added screenshots for clarity

[image: Combobox style]

[image: Drop down style]

Edit 2:
It looks like this only occurs when the combobox is set to not be editable (which is the correct behaviour for my program, so doesn't really help me.) When the combobox is set to editable, it obeys styles correctly. I've tried adding

```
QCombobox:!editable
{
    color:white;
}
```

but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: If you load Stylesheets from a file, maybe you have another stylsheet loaded afterwards in your application which overwrites that specific style? You could try using `QComboBox#YOUR_SPECIFIC_COMBO_BOX_NAME { color: white; }`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only just resolved this. It seems setting the padding property (with any value) on the combobox in the style sheet makes it properly obey the colour styling. I'm assuming it's down to some sort of bug that might only arise on certain set ups, but if anyone else is having the same problem, the following code would work (when compared with that in the original question):

```
QComboBox
{
    color:white;
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1,y2:1, stop: 1 rgba(228, 41, 81, 100), stop: 0 rgba(234, 107, 101, 100));
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,200);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px; /*This makes text colour work*/
}
```

Comment: This problem was bugging me for the last two hours... PADDING? Wow, I thank you for resolving this! But i wonder why? What kind of bug would cause this?

Comment: amazing. great job figuring this one out. I had the same problem.

Comment: I know SO discourages pointless comments but... THANK YOU!
`margin: 0px` also seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The View "inside" is a QListView.

```
QListView
{
  color: white;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, it's the actual combobox itself - not the drop down - which isn't accepting the change to colour. The drop down styles correctly (although using the colour from the QComboBox section, rather than it's own. However in my case this isn't a problem.)

Comment: Do you mean the current item? For the current item your code (first part) is perfectly fine (`QComboBox{ color: white; }`). Have you tried to delete all stylesheet code besides the color tag?

Comment: I've added some screenshots to the original question for clarity. I've tried creating a completely blank style sheet with only the combobox style sheet with colour, and it still only affects the dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

Using padding as a workaround might introduce some other problems. Perhaps setting *selection-color* should resolve this issue.

```
QComboBox
{
   selection-color: white;
}
```