# QComboBox text color doesn't change as expected

Tags: c++, css, qt, stylesheet, qcombobox

I have a simple QComboBox but I cannot figure out how to change the text color of the selected item. It stays black but it should be white. I used the color:white; properties but it seems to affect only the color of the popup item list.

this is my current stylesheet:

```
background: rgb(61,61,61);
color: rgb(255,255,255);
selection-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

the QComboBox keeps having this behaviour:

[image]

[image]

as you can see the selected item still has an unspecified black color.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5509

Comment: Is your combobox editable? How do you assign the stylesheet?

Comment: no, it isn't editable. I've assigned the css using QtCreator (it's not applied using ->setStyleSheet() method)

Comment: I see that other colors in your app are not standard too. Do you achieve it with CSS? Is it possible that your override the color somewhere? Try to create a new widget in QtCreator and set this stylesheet for it. Does it work?

Comment: It might be possible that some parent element is overriding the standard color, I'll check it out... but isn't it possible to force a color on a child element even if some parent is overriding it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible if another element has more elements in declaration hierarchy, for example, `QWidget:active` {} overrides `QComboBox` {}, `QWidget:active:hover` overrides both

Comment: ok ,so in the case some parent element is overriding my text color how to enforce it at the child-level?

Comment: The only way is to add more elements in the declaration of the GUI element: `QComboBox#name` or `ParentClass QComboBox#name` or even `ParentClass QComboBox#name:active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by including the padding property:

> QComboBox {   combobox-popup: 0;
>       color: white;
>       padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }

It seems setting the padding property (with any value) on the combobox in the style sheet makes it properly obey the colour styling.

See for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24824810/4022402